# Why doesn't chrome understand my scss source map?

Tags: sass, google-chrome-devtools, source-maps, gulp-sass, gulp-sourcemaps

I have an scss source file named `style.scss` which resides within `/style`:

```
@import 'reset';

body {
  background: #555555;
  color: white;
}
```

And another scss source file named `reset.scss` which resides within `/style`:

```
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

These are compiled by sass with a source map in to `style.min.css` which resides within `/style`:

```
*{padding:0;margin:0}body{background:#555555;color:white}

/*# sourceMappingURL=style.min.css.map */
```

This is the resulting map file, `style.min.css.map` which resides in `/style`:

```
{"version":3,"sources":["reset.scss","style.scss"],"names":[],"mappings":"AAAA,CAAC,AAAC,CACA,OAAO,CAAE,CAAE,CACX,MAAM,CAAE,CAAE,CCAZ,ADCC,ICDG,AAAC,CACH,UAAU,CAAE,OAAQ,CACpB,KAAK,CAAE,KAAM,CACd","file":"style.min.css","sourcesContent":["* {\r\n  padding: 0;\r\n  margin: 0;\r\n}","@import 'reset';\r\n\r\nbody {\r\n  background: #555555;\r\n  color: white;\r\n}\r\n"],"sourceRoot":"/style"}
```

I am using gulp to invoke sass. Here is the relevant configuration:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');

gulp.task('css', function() {
    return gulp.src('style/style.scss')
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(sass({outputStyle: 'compressed'}))
        .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.', {addComment: true, sourceRoot: '/style'}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('style/'))
});
```

**WebStorm 11.0.1 seems to understand this perfectly.**

**Chrome DevTools fails to understand the mapping correctly.** It is clearly trying; but all mappings point to `reset.scss` in various locations rather than the correct file and location. If I manually combine both files by replacing the `@import` with the actual content of `reset.scss`, the mappings work correctly in chrome, pointing to the correct location within `style.scss`.

Any idea what could be going on here?

**EDIT:** Microsoft Edge (the new IE in Windows 10) understands the mappings correctly within its in-browser dev tools.

**EDIT 2:** Firefox is experiencing the same issue as Chrome in exactly the same way.

**EDIT 3:** I Added another scss source file, `test.scss`:

```
div {
  color: red;
}
```

I then imported this in to the `style.scss` file which now looks like this:

```
@import 'reset';
@import 'test';

body {
  background: #555555;
  color: white;
}
```

Chrome seems to understand that there are multiple source files, but the mapped locations aren't correct, and `style.scss` is never pointed to.

Again, Edge and Webstorm work perfectly. Chrome and Firefox have the same issue.

Comment: If you compile it with Sass directly, rather than via Gulp, is the problem the same?

Comment: The output is a little different, but it did work that way. So that's a start; I just need to work out what the breaking difference is and then why. Good suggestion.

Comment: @cimmanon: I changed the gulp-sourcemaps settings to match the raw sass output better and the same issue occurred. The only real difference remaining was the actual mappings. I then copied the base64 encoded mappings from the working sass output in to the not-working gulp-sourcemaps output. This worked. So the issue boils down to the actual encoded mappings.

Comment: Additionally, I just reverted my gulp configuration changes so that the output is back in the format I want it to be in (not as closely matching the raw sass output), and then I again copy/pasted the base64 encoded mappings in to the output to replace the gulp generated encoded mappings, and it worked.

Comment: Okay, I did another test where I directly used `node-sass` from within another task, and the output worked. So the issue seems to likely be in the `gulp-sass` code.

Comment: I hooked up a debugger to the `gulp-sass` code and verified that the direct sourcemap output from `node-sass` from within `gulp-sass` works correctly. `vinyl-sourcemaps-apply` is definitely changing the sourcemap; it is reordering the `sources` array and there are a few differences in the mappings that look dubious. Further debugging required...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never did get around to debugging the actual sourcemap merge that I identified as buggy.

At the same time as I was trying to debug the merge, I submitted an issue to the gulp-sourcemaps project explaining that the problems with merging could be circumvented if the new sourcemap could overwrite rather than be merged. Obviously this is a workaround and not a fix, but it would get the job done.

The maintainer of the vinyl-sourcemaps-apply project made a change that causes a new sourcemap to overwrite when the existing source map has no mappings:

https://github.com/floridoo/vinyl-sourcemaps-apply/commit/30320c97c112f44ccba02dd73ce5bed1ad4361de

While this is not a 100% perfect solution, it is pragmatic and solves my immediate issue. The faulty merge is still an issue, but not one I have to deal with right now because my problem is solved by this workaround.

If you run in to a related issue and you legitimately do need to merge sourcemaps, the issue seems likely to be within the https://github.com/mozilla/source-map/ project.